# date range in timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Athens'
```

I want to list entries which are published between any date ranges.The query below starts listing entries which are published_at after 03:00 not 00:00 Any help will be appreciated.

```
@from_date = (Time.zone.now-1.day).to_date.to_datetime #iam trying to set time to 00:00
@to_date = (Time.zone.now+1.day).to_date.to_datetime
Entry.where(:spam => false, :published_at => @report_from_date..@report_to_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at using `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day`. For example, to show everything within the current day:

```
@from_date = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day # Returns 2011-08-08 00:00:00
@to_date = Time.zone.now.end_of_day # Returns 2011-08-08 23:59:59
```

Comment: `Date.parse("21/10/2011").beginning_of_day`